# $routeProvider not working when $location is injected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm currently working on an angularjs website, which features 1 module and for every tab a different controller. The problem that I'm having is that the following block of code is running perfectly and the user gets redirected to the login page and the controller starts.

```
angular.module('ScheidsPortal', ['ngRoute', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    })
    .otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
.run(function ($rootScope, Interface) {

});
```

However when the `$location` is injected in the run function:

```
.run(function ($rootScope, Interface, $location) {
```

The routing feature stops working, no redirection is used and the controller isn't loading. Using the `$location` instance in controllers doesn't produce any problems.

What is missing?

Comment: what is the error in cosole?

Comment: The log in completely empty, no warnings or errors

Comment: create a plunker for your issue

Comment: I created a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/aFwgxwI9aHMh6n0xRFdu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my own problem: in the index.html I used a component named 'menu' as the root of my app.

```
<body>
   <menu></menu>
</body>
```

The `<div ng-view></div>` was part of the template of the menu-component.
Since this component was sometimes not rendered, the $routeProvider wasn't always loaded. Putting the `<div ng-view></div>` in the index.html worked wonders.

In the plunker you can see it works: in the console log it shows 'login controller' showing that controller is being loaded. (somehow the html is not showing in the page, but in the developer console, F12, you can see the html code)